# Send an image using PIL and StringIO

Tags: python, sockets, pygame, python-imaging-library, stringio

I've just started using PIL, StringIO and Pygame, therefore I have some troubles with getting the results I want.
I try to make a screen sharing software, and in order to achieve that I need to be able to send an image from one computer to another and show it there using Pygame.
Here is the server:

```
#region - - - - - - I M P O R T S - - - - - -
import socket
import select
from PIL import ImageGrab
from PIL import Image
from cStringIO import StringIO
import base64
#endregion
#region - - - - - - C O N S T A N T S - - - - - -
PORT = 8820
CONCURRENT_USERS = 5
#endregion

server_socket = socket.socket()
server_socket.bind(('', PORT))
server_socket.listen(CONCURRENT_USERS)
clients_list = []
while True:
    read, write, error = select.select([server_socket] + clients_list, [], [], 0)
    for i in read:
        if i is server_socket:
            client_socket, client_address = server_socket.accept()
            clients_list.append(client_socket)
        for i in clients_list:
            img = ImageGrab.grab()
            img_str = StringIO()
            img.save(img_str, "JPEG")
            try:
                i.send(base64.b64encode(img_str.getvalue()))
            except socket.error:
                clients_list.remove(i)
                i.close()
```

And there is the client:

```
import socket
import pygame
import sys
from PIL import Image
from StringIO import StringIO
import base64
IP = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 8820
client_socket = socket.socket()
client_socket.connect((IP, PORT))
WIDTH = 720
HEIGHT = 480
pygame.init()
size = WIDTH, HEIGHT
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
count = 0
while True:
    count += 1
    for e in pygame.event.get():
        if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
    str_img = ''
    chunk = client_socket.recv(1024)
    while chunk:
        str_img += chunk
        chunk = client_socket.recv(1024)
    str_img = base64.b64decode(str_img)
    img = Image.open(str_img)
    screen.blit(img, (0, 0))
    screen.display.flip()
```

The Pygame window doesn't show any image and also it crashes after a few seconds.
I've tried several methods before using StringIO (I've tried using Pickle, and some Image methods) and nothing worked for me.
Can anyone spot the issue? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: You may find http://stackoverflow.com/q/2915030/190597 helpful. Note that you must call `shutdown` or `close` from the server to cause `recv` to return `''` in the client. Do not send `'done'` from the server unless the client is also prepared to remove `'done'` from the bytes received. Since there is no advantage to sending `'done'`, you might as well not send it at all.

Comment: I thought about doing something like that, but I'll have to reopen the socket for every image. Won't that make the whole process much slower?
What is the fastest way to know that the data is over?

Comment: In that case you could send the size of the string first, followed by the string itself. That way, the client will know how many bytes to expect. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/27429611/190597 for example.

Comment: Note also that `send` and `recv` are [not guaranteed to send or receive every byte](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2969606/190597). So you need to loop-and-check to make sure you've received the proper number of bytes. See for example tdelaney's `_get_block` and `_send_block`.

Comment: @unutbu Is this absolutely necessary? because I'm trying to make this whole thing work as fast as possible and I'm affraid it will slow it down by much.

Comment: It is necessary to use some kind of protocol so the client can recognize when one image ends and the next one begins. There is no getting around the need. You might do better sending *information* about the motion of objects instead of sending binary images however. Then the client can compute the image for itself.

Comment: The `_send_block` is unnecessary; `s.sendall` would work just as well.  But you
will need something like `_get_block`. The looping when calling `s.recv` is
absolutely necessary if you don't want your code to be buggy.

Comment: According to the [Socket Programming HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/sockets.html#performance) you will get better performance using non-blocking sockets and calling `select.select` to handle writing to multiple clients.

Comment: I am already using select.select for some of the code.for now though, my method is as follows:
- I'm getting the size of the string (in bytes)
- with a while loop I'm checking (while size > 0) and keep receiving 2048 bytes at a time and reducing 2048 from the size variable.
I managed to see an image on the pygame screen, but after one image the size gets a part of the image before or after (i'm not sure which) and therefore crashes when I try to change it to an integer. Do you have any idea why it happens? (If something I've said isn't clear tell me and I'll rephrase it)

Comment: The devil is in the details. We'd need to see the code to find the error. Are you using `_get_block` and `send_msg`? They are designed to solve this problem. Remember that `s.recv(2048)` is not guaranteed to receive 2048 bytes....

Comment: I haven't tried using _get_block and send_msg yet, because I'm affraid it will get slower, and because I'm sending an image maybe if one or two bytes will be missing it won't be so bad(?) - (like when you use UDP)
Can I show you the code? and if so, where?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79151/discussion-between-pystudent51-and-unutbu).

Comment: I would try to get working code before worrying about performance. I don't think you can just drop bytes and not worry about it :) If you really want better performance, I would focus on sending object motion information (e.g. ball moves to (100,100)) instead of binary images. [Network communication is many orders of magnitude slower](http://norvig.com/21-days.html#answers) than execution of a typical CPU instruction. So compressing or *reducing* the amount of network communication is likely to be the most effective way to make your program perform better.